# Specify dynamic details to go into the MessageCard using NLog.Targets.Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, nlog, .net-6.0

I am using this nuget package: NLog.Targets.Teams. (https://github.com/task-it/TaskIt.NLog.Targets.Teams) I have set up a MSTeams target in my NLog config, and I'm able to successfully get a message to appear in Teams with the information I've configured in the CustomMessageCard class. Great so far. But what I don't see how to do is to dynamically set some specific values to go into the card at runtime. It seems like it only works with the configuration defined in the CustomMessageCard class. Is it possible to somehow specify different values at runtime?

Comment: Could you please go through following document if its help you in any way. https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configure-from-code

Comment: Could you please confirm if you need further help?

Comment: I did read through that, but it still wasn't clear to me that there is helpful information there. Maybe I'm missing it, but I didn't see how to do something like: for a given exception, I might want to add a comment or other piece of info that's not included in the CustomMessageCard class.

Comment: @user1298298 - Could you please share the repro steps and docs that you are following for CustomeMessageCard?
So that we can try it from our end.

Comment: @user1298298 - You can pass dynamic values also in Cards like in Adaptive Card you can define using dollar symbol ($) and use curly braces;
{
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "text": "${titleText}",
      "size": "default",
      "weight": "bolder"
    },

And while preparing the JSON Card, you can pass dynamic value.

Comment: Created pull-request: https://github.com/task-it/TaskIt.NLog.Targets.Teams/pull/8